# Volume testing in Tuleap

Tags: volume, tuleap

We are now using Tuleap latest version in our Office, around 2000 employees are using it for project management and also, we slightly modified the workflow to replace our internal ticketing system. So currently, we use Tuleap for project management as well as our ticketing system. We get around 2000 tickets per day.

Just wanted to understand how much volume our Tuleap can handle, I looked at the DB structure and it looks like each action with respect to a ticket is stored as an entry. So request to please let me know if we need to plan anything pro-actively to ensure our Tuleap systems handles huge volume?

Am afraid what if my instance crashes due to huge volume of tickets day-to-day. Need experts’ advice please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your instance will probably not crash due to huge volume of tickets day-to-day. You may experience slowdowns but you should not have crashs. It is really hard to answer your question as you do not provide information about the hardware currently supporting your Tuleap's instance. You need to size your hardware reasonably enough regarding to your usage for sure: it all depends on which services you use and so on.